# I am not receiving response data from the client to the Java Spring Boot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, tcp, observable

I'm new to sockets in java.
I would like to know why I am not able to receive the data from the client to the server.

after making the connection, I can send data to the client, but with "client.observable.subscribe" I can not see the return data

Server code:

```
@GetMapping("/desktop/{client}")
public DeferredResult<String> getScreenshot(@PathVariable("client") String clientName) {
    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    Client client = ClientListenerService.getClient(clientName);
    if (client == null) {
        result.setResult(new JSONObject().put("error", "Requested client was not found").toString());
        return result;
    }
    Long requestID = client.getRequestID();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("id", requestID);
    request.put("type", RequestType.GET_SCREENSHOT.getValue());
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(request.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        result.setResult(new JSONObject().put("error", "Failed to write to the socket, exception: " + ex).toString());
        return result;
    }
    Runnable task = () -> {
        client.observable.subscribe((response) -> {
            JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
            if (responseJson.has("id") && responseJson.getLong("id") == requestID) {
                result.setResult(response);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } 
        }, (error) -> {});
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
    return result;
}
```

Client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socketClient = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
      socketClient = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream())),true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot set I/O channels for connection");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        String line;
        line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Response server: " + line);
        
        out.println(line); // Send to server
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socketClient.close();
}
```

I hope your help community, thank you

Comment: Do you have an error? Have you configure you spring server to listen to port `2222`?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I connect and send data from the server to the client, but I cannot